# API requests include time, docs indicate only date

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm looking for clarification on what seems like a difference between the fullcalendar timezone documentation, and the actual behavior.

When the fullcalendar performs an API request from the month view, I receive what matches the documentation:

```
start=2017-01-01&end=2017-01-02
```

However, when the request occurs on the week or day view, I receive:

```
start=2017-01-01T00:00:00&end=2017-01-02T00:00:00
```

Based on the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) for `no timezone`, I expected the request to only be the date, without the time added on.

Anyone know if this is the correct behavior?

I'm just looking to confirm what's in the documentation. If this is expected, then I will look over what I am doing on my end.

This is my fullcalendar configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var events_url;
    var default_date;
    var default_view;
    var element = document.querySelector('#calendar');
    if (element !== null)
    {
        events_url = element.dataset.eventsUrl;
        default_date = element.dataset.date;
        default_view = element.dataset.calendarView;
        default_view = fc_view_name[default_view];
    }

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: default_date,
        defaultView: default_view,
        editable: false,
        events: events_url,
        eventLimit: true,
        firstDay: 1,

        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view)
        {
            requestDialog(event.event_url, {'next': window.location.pathname});
        },

        viewRender: function(view, element)
        {
            var $calendar = $('#calendar');
            var url_builder = $calendar.data('url-builder');
            var date = $calendar.fullCalendar('getDate');
            var public_calendar = $calendar.data('calendar');
            var view_name = reverse_view_name[view.name];
            setNextUrl(url_builder, view_name, date, public_calendar);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Post some sample code of your API Request

Comment: I'm not understanding what code you would be looking for, this would be the request generated from fullcalender.

Here's the config I have set for the fullcalendar:
    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: default_date,
    defaultView: default_view,
    editable: false,
    events: events_url,
    eventLimit: true,
    firstDay: 1,

Comment: Show your fullcalendar configuration as it is in your javascript code. The entire configuration.